# Ios safariviewcontroller not tracking the urls

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, progressive-web-apps

I have developed a progressive web app (PWA) application in MVC using dotnet. It is working fine in offline and online for safari and chrome. Now i want to develop an ios app which will call my pwa url(in other words pwa app is inside ios app). Now on particular url i want to jump back to native app screen. But i am unable to track urls in safari view controller. I don't want to use wkwebview as it is not supporting service workers for pwa. Can any one tell is there any other way to track urls or any other third party webview some thing like, so that it will support service worker and track the urls.

Thanks

Mohammed Sujavuddin

Comment: You can't do anything with safari view controller.

Comment: @Lumialxk do you know anyother third party webview which will support tracking urls and supporting serviceworkers

Comment: All iOS web browser is using Apple's kernel. Safari View Controller is designed for build-in web browser so user will have a private and smooth experience.